# Express / CSP / ejs / inline-scripts & NONCES: How to?

Tags: express, ejs, content-security-policy, nonce

**Here's what I am trying to do:** 
1.) Generate a NONCE using [express-csp-header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-csp-header) 
2.) Inject generated NONCE into an [.ejs](https://ejs.co/) template 
3.) Use that NONCE to allow an inline-script inside that template

**Here's what actually happens (as far as I can tell):** 
1.) NONCE is generated 
2.) NONCE is successfully passed to 'index.ejs' and then forwarded to 'head.ejs'
3.) The template ('index.ejs') gets rendered and due to static assets being requested a new NONCE (or several NONCES) get generated ... 
4.) Which invalidates the NONCE passed to the template

**Here's what I am currently doing:**

```js
// server.js
const { expressCspHeader,NONCE } = require("express-csp-header");

app.use(
    expressCspHeader({
        directives: {
            "script-src": [
                SELF,
                [NONCE],
            ],
        },
    })
);

// middleware to log the current NONCE attached to the 'request object'
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(" ---------------------------------> NONCE", req.nonce);
    next();
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
console.log("app.get('/')");
console.log("passed NONCE to '/' route: ------> ", req.nonce);
res.render("pages/index", {
  nonce: req.nonce,
  });
});
```

```ejs
<!-- index.ejs -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <!-- Passing the received NONCE to 'head.ejs' -->
    <%- include ("../partials/head.ejs", {nonce: nonce}) %>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

```ejs
<!-- head.ejs -->
<title>Title</title>
<% console.log("head.ejs: received NONCE:   ------>", nonce) %>
<!-- My Inline Script -->
<script nonce='<%= nonce %>'>
  console.log("I am an inline script!")
</script>

<!-- more CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/css/global/header.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/css/global/footer.css" />
```

**When I use [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) to log all requests, my problem becomes obvious:**

```
---------------------------------> generated NONCE:  7CpDuxCZCSrRfmNCVBnkUg==
app.get('/')
passed NONCE to '/' route: ------>  7CpDuxCZCSrRfmNCVBnkUg==
head.ejs: received NONCE:   ------> 7CpDuxCZCSrRfmNCVBnkUg==
GET / 200 30.562 ms - -
---------------------------------> generated NONCE:  fpcpM9o/Ab3g5bSUmymAOg==
---------------------------------> generated NONCE:  5ElxDy+WboVga1We5L/v1g==
GET /static/css/global/header.css 304 4.227 ms - -
GET /static/css/global/footer.css 304 2.141 ms - -
```

So how do I get around this problem? Thanks to anyone reading this, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's what really happened:**

1.) The NONCES were working, I just didn't test them on a regular **script** but on one that had other CSP issues than an invalid NONCE.

2.) I didn't know how the Express static folder works, which led to a bad flow of requests. The line: `app.use("/static", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "static")));` 
was sitting above the 'Express CSP Header' middleware. So every GET request to a file in `/static` ran through the CSP-Middleware first and served the static asset later. Here are logs before and after moving the 'express.static' line further up the chain.

BEFORE:

```
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  Y8fG4FXkWGCa66b4DNNtOw==
app.get('/')
passed NONCE to '/' route: ------>  Y8fG4FXkWGCa66b4DNNtOw==
head.ejs: received NONCE:   ------> Y8fG4FXkWGCa66b4DNNtOw==
GET / 200 35.642 ms - -
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  TnaEqWMKHwRNG5LyP/4YFA==
GET /static/css/global/header.css 304 2.280 ms - -
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  RGJrqm3qZspjUHKlMagm5Q==
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  rHO67xdswBY9N4wBDfoyFg==
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  8LpyqQdvIa28HTIjTR9pKw==
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  3v31KoRNjYwf+ajfXNNXhw==
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  sMUYhgkcYDMXHDMNOTnRlA==
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  0Zaa33QPteaaWUBbZLhZXA==
GET /static/css/global/footer.css 304 3.056 ms - -
GET /static/css/global/global.css 304 2.734 ms - -
GET /static/slick/slick-theme.css 200 5.107 ms - -
GET /static/css/global/hamburger.css 200 3.803 ms - -
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  Ly7ri0OUnaJeSTRXrO2Uxg==
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  zAuXEhaJ2qpNP1FmLGYnHw==
GET /static/svelte/svelte.css 200 3.464 ms - -
GET /static/slick/slick.css 200 3.135 ms - -
GET /static/svelte/svelte-bundle.js 304 1.730 ms - -
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  Xxh74qC5kvUs/6iVP5Ckcg==
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  ndLVatznuuJo3lxnSQn07g==
GET /static/script.js 304 1.184 ms - -
GET /static/index_slider.js 200 1.215 ms - 853
GET /static/css/layouts/index.css 200 4.673 ms - -
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  rmEunrBHysX1cBANuHcE9A==
GET /static/slick/slick.min.js 304 0.528 ms - -
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  VVwVknnFqpwHI+UAVGDiQA==
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  y9xb6FAw+noMTMlCMBN47g==
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  huz3j8ipoAGkttl58TuV6A==
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  /v8kVXw7eGvDcL8N1Uoz4g==
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  jqiudorrrgj/8K+8swOhpg==
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  csT6iBmrcaXxXrnnWO9qUQ==
GET /static/images/rw.webp 304 2.959 ms - -
GET /static/images/svg/logo_grey.svg 304 2.823 ms - -
GET /static/images/icon_facebook.svg 304 2.636 ms - -
GET /static/images/icon_twitter.svg 304 2.506 ms - -
GET /static/images/icon_instagram.svg 304 2.457 ms - -
GET /static/images/icon_hamburger_grey.svg 304 2.211 ms - -
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  uJQGA7rnyYyZWMOo5Vg4yQ==
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  OOUmFVdAahTWtR+PsKOdFg==
GET /static/images/icon_slider_next.svg 304 0.656 ms - -
GET /static/images/icon_slider_prev.svg 304 0.572 ms - -
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  J9oz/sb0cmlhjmy47Hmf1Q==
GET /static/slick/slick.min.js 304 1.046 ms - -
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  jWb0xdpZdpUGUTjAr32dVw==
GET /static/svelte/svelte-bundle.js 304 0.609 ms - -
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  0vGtGk3oRXYEFEf0Re6JFw==
GET /static/script.js 304 0.558 ms - -
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  tIeYKbs/NhOWWr3GAo8scw==
GET /static/svelte/svelte-bundle.js.map 304 0.422 ms - -
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  TXSm/L4nTgd5mVRQGmyOtg==
GET /static/index_slider.js 304 0.624 ms - -
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  yrGsmQMHw8+/ap/qdquy+g==
GET /static/slick/ajax-loader.gif 304 0.568 ms - -
```

AFTER:

```
Server running on port 1339
Before Express CSP Header Middleware
-------------------------------------------> generated NONCE:  wkMabZKUD8et0YL4qjHzvw==
app.get('/')
passed NONCE to '/' route: ------>  wkMabZKUD8et0YL4qjHzvw==
head.ejs: received NONCE:   ------> wkMabZKUD8et0YL4qjHzvw==
GET / 200 37.994 ms - -
GET /static/css/global/header.css 304 1.253 ms - -
GET /static/css/global/footer.css 304 1.497 ms - -
GET /static/css/global/hamburger.css 304 1.392 ms - -
GET /static/svelte/svelte.css 304 1.402 ms - -
GET /static/svelte/svelte-bundle.js 304 1.355 ms - -
GET /static/css/global/global.css 304 1.276 ms - -
GET /static/slick/slick.css 200 1.454 ms - -
GET /static/slick/slick-theme.css 200 1.113 ms - -
GET /static/script.js 304 0.539 ms - -
GET /static/index_slider.js 200 2.022 ms - 853
GET /static/slick/slick.min.js 304 0.959 ms - -
GET /static/css/layouts/index.css 200 1.647 ms - -
GET /static/images/icon_facebook.svg 304 0.624 ms - -
GET /static/images/icon_twitter.svg 304 0.747 ms - -
GET /static/images/icon_slider_prev.svg 304 0.581 ms - -
GET /static/images/icon_slider_next.svg 304 0.473 ms - -
GET /static/images/rw.webp 200 3.326 ms - 44096
GET /static/images/icon_instagram.svg 304 1.325 ms - -
GET /static/images/icon_hamburger_grey.svg 304 1.371 ms - -
GET /static/images/svg/logo_grey.svg 200 3.797 ms - -
GET /static/slick/slick.min.js 304 0.383 ms - -
GET /static/svelte/svelte-bundle.js 304 0.533 ms - -
GET /static/script.js 304 0.412 ms - -
GET /static/svelte/svelte-bundle.js.map 304 0.340 ms - -
GET /static/index_slider.js 304 0.317 ms - -
GET /static/slick/ajax-loader.gif 304 0.267 ms - -
```